# How to write "set batch operation" in Python?

Tags: python, set, union

I'm a beginner in Python.

The codes that works is following:

```
a_set = set('a', 'b', 'c')
result_set = set()
for str1 in a_set:
    res = 'prefix-' + str1
    result_set.add(res)
```

The codes I want is similar to:

```
a_set = set('a', 'b', 'c')
result_set = set('prefix-' + c for c in a_set)
```

I think it may be more pythonic? But it doesn't work. What can I try next?

Comment: If you replace your `set(...)` calls with set comprehensions it works fine `{...}`

Comment: The "codes that works" does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a set comprehension. The syntax is the exact same as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps) except `[` and `]` are replaced with `{` and `}`, respectively.

```py
result_set = {'prefix-' + c for c in a_set}
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzG@OLVEwVahWj1RXUdBPQlEJKvXchWlFpfmlMAlC4pS0zIrdNUVtBWSFdLyi4BkZp4CWHMtV0FRZl6JBkKH5v//AA)

Answer (score 2):

Change the `set` constructor input into a list:

```
a_set = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])  # <-- do not pass multiple strings, pass a single list
result_set = set('prefix-' + c for c in a_set)
print(result_set)
```

or since you already know the `set` contents:

```
a_set = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
result_set = {f'prefix-{c}' for c in a_set}
print(result_set)
```